# representing manytomanyfield with extra attributes in django

Tags: sql, django, model, foreign-keys, relation

I have a situation where i need to store a **table of "Product"'s and a table of "Order"'s** on these products.

**One order consists of many ("Product", "Quantity") tuples**  where quantity is a float expressed in tonnes.

I considered the followng implementation, but i don't think having a table of arbitrary products and quantities would be a very good design decision.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)

class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    unit = "tonnes"
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    quantity = models.FloatField('Quantity')

class Order(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('ProductOrder')
    date = models.DateField('Date')
```

Am I overlooking an obvious solution? How would you implement this relationship to lead to the most DRY code. (PS. I don't want to have separate lists of products and quantities and have to rely implicitly on their ordering.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In django, you can use [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to create such intermediate table and maintain order specific attributes in there.

You can implement it as

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through="OrderDetail")
    date = models.DateField('Date')

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    unit = "tonnes"
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order')
    quantity = models.FloatField('Quantity')
```

The documentation explains how to use and work with such design.

Comment: So I do need the foreign key field in OrderDetail but I'd rather to refer to Order.OrderItems than Order.Products as that gives me access to the quantities.

Comment: The 2 foreign keys in `OrderDetail` are required by django for `through` relationship.